# cassandra nodetool error system cannot find path

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, cassandra-cli

I'm trying to run `nodetool -h localhost ring` using cmd in C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin but it is showing error:

```
Starting NodeTool
The system cannot find the path specified
```

Actually i want to run NodeTool utility to `nodetool flush key_space column_family` or `nodetool compact  key_space column_family`. Are there any other ways to do it ? CQL? OpsCenter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rarely work on Windows, so maybe it's a setup step I'm missing, but had the same problem. A DSC issue has been opened. Will get back to you.

The problem was I had Java 6 installed and JAVA_HOME pointed to it. I installed the latest JRE 7, set JAVA_HOME to point to it, and restarted the computer. Now, nodetool -h localhost status shows the status of my single node. After getting nodetool to work, I saw that there is a JRE installed with the Windows 64-bit version of Cassandra. I would try just setting JAVA_HOME to point to that one. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to know if i use UUID as row key & then backup to upload it on other host/cloud then will it affect the UUID generation ? Can it lead to same row keys be produced on different hosts/cloud ?

Comment: Yes, using UUID as the Cassandra row key is common. Cassandra is designed to be used in a cluster of hosts and by design, replicates data to other nodes in the cluster, but manages the distributed data so it is not a problem to have same row key on multiple hosts in the cluster, but in keeping with the Cassandra architecture. Please see https://academy.datastax.com/topics/architecture or  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployConfigRep.html. Sorry the docs are Linux-oriented.

Comment: Ok Thanks. How to take backup or export data ? Till now i know about 1: Through Script (Time Consuming: It looks best?) 2: Export to CSV (Will be slow i guess if it's a BigData?) 3: sstable2json (Will be slow i guess if it's a BigData?) Any other efficient method ?

Comment: Backup: http://website-staging.dev.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html Export/import tools: http://website-staging.dev.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/migrating.html

Comment: It's Asking for Username & Password ?

Comment: What's asking for a password? You configured internal authorization? http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secure_config_native_authorize_t.html Try the default superuser password: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/share/glossary/gloss_superuser.html

Comment: No, i think http://website-staging.dev.datastax.com/documentation  is only for premium user or some registration required to open the link.

Comment: Sorry, website-staging should be www.datastax.com. The correct URLs are http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html and http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/migrating.html